# Excel - How to find strings in Column B based on multiple rows in Column A and return the corresponding row in Column C?

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns in Excel 2007+.

Col A contains search text (text that I want to search with).
Col B contains all the text that I want to search from.
Col C contains another set of value that will not be searched, but will be output to Col D if there is a match.

Basically, I need a formula in Col D whereby the logic goes like this:

```
FOR EACH row in Col A,
IF (a row in B) contains text from each row in A, D = C.
```

Example:

```
  A     B         C         D
1 dog   dog bone  dog woof  dog woof
2 cat   dog bait  dog meow  dog meow
3 bird  wolf      asd
4 pig   cat       we        we
```

As you can see, a search for A1 is performed in the entire column B. For every row in Col B that matches A1, the corresponding row in C is output to D. Since the string "dog" is found in B1 and B2, C1 and C2 are output to D1 and D2 respectively.

B3 does not match or contain any text from Col A, so nothing it output.

B4 contains "cat" from A2, so C4 is output to D4.

After the search result is done, then I will filter the table based on Col D. Basically I want to exclude rows whereby Col B contains no text from any rows in Col A, and I check Col C's data based on this filter.

I've tried to use INDEX and MATCH and SEARCH, but I just can't wrap my head around the formula and its output.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against VBA when you can achieve the required results easily with worksheet formulas

Put the following formula into cell **D1** and drag down

```
{=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$4,$B1),0)),$C1,"")}
```

It's an array formula so leave out the curly braces and enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be able to handle Unicode characters though. It works fine with English text, but fails when there are non-English unicode text involved. Nonetheless, this is a good enough solution. I'll adapt this and work something out.

Answer (score 0):

This will be achieved by VBA macro.
use below code, it should suffice your need.

```
Sub pSearchPart()

    Dim rngColA         As Range
    Dim rngColAEach      As Range
    Dim rngColB         As Range
    Dim rngColBEach     As Range

    'Assign range in Column A Considering data to be on Sheet1
    Set rngColA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
    'Assign range in Column B Considering data to be on Sheet1
    Set rngColB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B4")

    'Loop in each cells to check string in Column A on Column B
    For Each rngColAEach In rngColA.Cells
        If Trim(rngColAEach) <> "" Then
            For Each rngColBEach In rngColB.Cells
                If Trim(rngColBEach) <> "" Then
                    If InStr(1, rngColBEach, rngColAEach) > 0 Then
                       rngColBEach.Offset(, 2) = rngColBEach.Offset(, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next rngColBEach
        End If
    Next rngColAEach

    'Clear Memory
    Set rngColA = Nothing
    Set rngColAEach = Nothing
    Set rngColB = Nothing
    Set rngColBEach = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying to avoid VBA as the worksheet formulas are the most portable and adaptable. Wouldn't want to keep bothering you if I need adjustment to the code.